# Docker M1 - Using Ubuntu + MySQL: /bin/sh errors on latest update Docker Desktop 4.2.0

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, dockerfile, apple-m1

I'm struggling to get build my project after updating my Docker.

My previous working DockerFile:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04


ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV TZ=UTC

RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y gnupg gosu curl ca-certificates zip unzip git supervisor sqlite3 libcap2-bin libpng-dev python2 \
    && mkdir -p ~/.gnupg \
    && chmod 600 ~/.gnupg \
    && echo "disable-ipv6" >> ~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf \
    && apt-key adv --homedir ~/.gnupg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys E5267A6C \
    && apt-key adv --homedir ~/.gnupg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys C300EE8C \
    && echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ppa_ondrej_php.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y php7.4-cli php7.4-dev \
       php7.4-pgsql php7.4-sqlite3 php7.4-gd \
       php7.4-curl php7.4-memcached \
       php7.4-imap php7.4-mysql php7.4-mbstring \
       php7.4-xml php7.4-zip php7.4-bcmath php7.4-soap \
       php7.4-intl php7.4-readline php7.4-pcov \
       php7.4-msgpack php7.4-igbinary php7.4-ldap \
       php7.4-redis \
    && php -r "readfile('http://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer \
    && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_15.x | bash - \
    && apt-get install -y nodejs \
    && curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - \
    && echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y yarn \
    && apt-get install -y mysql-client \
    && apt-get install -y postgresql-client \
    && apt-get -y autoremove \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
```

With the Platform: `platform: linux/x86_64` in my `Docker-Compose`.

However, it now isn't working after updating Docker and I'm clueless why.

Returns the response now of:

> After this operation, 116 MB of additional disk space will be used.
> Get:1 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_15.x focal/main arm64 nodejs
> arm64 15.14.0-deb-1nodesource1 [24.8 MB] debconf: delaying package
> configuration, since apt-utils is not installed Fetched 24.8 MB in 2s
> (12.5 MB/s) Selecting previously unselected package nodejs. (Reading
> database ... 21576 files and directories currently installed.)
> Preparing to unpack .../nodejs_15.14.0-deb-1nodesource1_arm64.deb ...
> Unpacking nodejs (15.14.0-deb-1nodesource1) ... Setting up nodejs
> (15.14.0-deb-1nodesource1) ... Processing triggers for man-db
> (2.9.1-1) ... Warning: apt-key output should not be parsed (stdout is
> not a terminal) gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found. Segmentation fault 1

> error occurred:
> * Status: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update     && apt-get install -y gnupg gosu curl ca-certificates zip unzip git
> supervisor sqlite3 libcap2-bin libpng-dev python2     && mkdir -p
> ~/.gnupg     && chmod 600 ~/.gnupg     && echo "disable-ipv6" >>
> ~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf     && apt-key adv --homedir ~/.gnupg
> --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys E5267A6C     && apt-key adv --homedir ~/.gnupg --keyserver
> hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys C300EE8C     && echo "deb
> http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal main" >
> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ppa_ondrej_php.list     && apt-get update
> && apt-get install -y php7.4-cli php7.4-dev        php7.4-pgsql
> php7.4-sqlite3 php7.4-gd        php7.4-curl php7.4-memcached
> php7.4-imap php7.4-mysql php7.4-mbstring        php7.4-xml php7.4-zip
> php7.4-bcmath php7.4-soap        php7.4-intl php7.4-readline
> php7.4-pcov        php7.4-msgpack php7.4-igbinary php7.4-ldap
> php7.4-redis     && php -r
> "readfile('http://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php --
> --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer     && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_15.x | bash -     && apt-get install
> -y nodejs     && curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -     && echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable
> main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list     && apt-get update     &&
> apt-get install -y yarn     && apt-get install -y mysql-client     &&
> apt-get install -y postgresql-client     && apt-get -y autoremove
> && apt-get clean     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*'
> returned a non-zero code: 2, Code: 2

Steps tried (Specifying Ubuntu version in case there's some incompatibilities):

```
FROM --platform=linux/arm64/v8 ubuntu:18.04
```

> Error 1: Unable to locate package python2

```
FROM --platform=linux/arm64/v8 ubuntu:21.04
```

> Error 1: The following packages have unmet dependencies:  libxml2 :
> Depends: libicu66 (>= 66.1-1~) but it is not installable  php7.4-intl
> : Depends: libicu66 (>= 66.1-1~) but it is not installable
>
> Error 2: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages. 1
> error occurred: Status: The command '/bin/sh -c [....] returned a
> non-zero code: 100, Code: 100

```
FROM --platform=linux/arm64/v8 ubuntu:22.04
```

> Error 1: The following packages have unmet dependencies:  libxml2 :
> Depends: libicu66 (>= 66.1-1~) but it is not installable  php7.4-intl
> : Depends: libicu66 (>= 66.1-1~) but it is not installable
>
> Error 2: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages. 1
> error occurred: Status: The command '/bin/sh -c [....] returned a
> non-zero code: 100, Code: 100

Docker-Compose:

I have specified my platform to now be `platform: linux/amd64`rather than `platform: linux/x86_64` as per to the docs. Tried using `linux/arm64` but that didn't work either (Same errors produced).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, I was being an idiot yesterday night.

Solution A: (In my case): Downgrade back to Docker Desktop version 4.0.0. I was using Intel Images so that's why I had to specify `x86_64`.

A more better solution would to change all my images be Arm64 and Intel based as well as it being compatible with Ubuntu + Mysql (currently docker Is recommending to use MariaDB for now)

However - seeing that Docker is still relatively unstable and can stop your build process at any moment, I advise anyone to update the Docker for M1 with caution!